# Adding multiple values to the same Key either via list or add a suffix if a duplicate key is present python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates, key-value

I extracted Module_name from a JSON file in which a key Social is present twice

```
with open(filename,'r') as jsonFile:
                        data = json.load(jsonFile)
                        module = data.get('UserIntents') #get the key "UserIntents" 
                        for bcd in module: #inside the UserIntents:
                            if 'ModuleName' in bcd: #extracted ModuleName
                                    Module_Name = bcd.get('ModuleName') #extract ModuleName information
                                    Intent_Name = bcd.get('IntentName') #extract Intent Name 
                                    data = {Module_Name: Intent_Name}
                                    ModName.update(data)
```

Output of data :

```
print data {'ClickUrl': 'HTTP'}
print data {'AngryUser': 'HATE'}
print data {'HelloGoodBye': 'HELLO'}
print data {'Social': 'TEAM_WELLNESS'}
print data {'Social': 'TEAM_MEMBERS'}
```

It has a key "Social" but with different values

As of now, a dictionary: ModName is chosen to store this but it ofcourse overrides the TEAM_WELLNESS as it doesn't accept duplicates.
Now, even it is being stores as list like

```
data = {ModName: [Intent_Name]}
```

It is still overriding the previous value, how to handle such cases with same key and diffrent values?

The other way is check if Module_name has the same content twice, it will change the second occurence by appending a suffix, something like SOCIAL_1 , SOCIAL_2 to avoid duplicates but I am new to python and not sure how to handle this functionality

Current Output using Dictionary :

```
ModName=  {'ClickUrl': 'HTTP', 'AngryUser': 'HATE', 'HelloGoodBye': 'HELLO', 'Social': 'TEAM_MEMBERS'}
```

Expected Output :

```
ModName=  {'ClickUrl': 'HTTP', 'AngryUser': 'HATE', 'HelloGoodBye': 'HELLO', 'Social': 'TEAM_MEMBERS','Social_1':'TEAM_WELLNESS'}
```

Comment: Can you show the part of the input JSON that has the same key twice and also show your required output

Comment: "UserIntents":[{
   
   "FirstVariation": "How is the Alchemy team doing?",
   "IntentName": "TEAM_WELLNESS",
   "ModuleName": "Social",
   },
   
   {
   
   "FirstVariation": "I'd like to learn more about the team",
   "IntentName": "TEAM_MEMBERS",
   "ModuleName": "Social",
   
   }]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited the code with the current and expected output for better clarity

Comment: There is nothing in the code shown that's going to create keys 'Social' and 'Social_1'. Would it not be better to have a key 'Social' with a list as its associated value?

Comment: I tried that already like {Social : [TEAM_WELLNESS, TEAM_MEMBERS]} but it's not giving the relavant output. I am looking for something to add a suffix if there are two same keys are present in the JSON file , like i mentioned in the expected output so that it will always remain separate rather than in a list

Comment: That can certainly be done but why? You would end up with a dictionary containing keys that no one can use without having to write special code to search for them. How would anyone know, for example, that the dictionary contains 'Social_99'? It really doesn't make sense to do it that way

Answer (score 0):

This does **not** generate the required output. It is a suggestion of how the output might be better managed.

```
data = {"UserIntents": [{"FirstVariation": "How is the Alchemy team doing?", "IntentName": "TEAM_WELLNESS", "ModuleName": "Social", }, {
    "FirstVariation": "I'd like to learn more about the team", "IntentName": "TEAM_MEMBERS", "ModuleName": "Social", }]}

ModName = {'ClickUrl': 'HTTP', 'AngryUser': 'HATE', 'HelloGoodBye': 'HELLO'}

MN = 'ModuleName'
IN = 'IntentName'
UI = 'UserIntents'

for d in data[UI]:
    ModName.setdefault(d[MN], []).append(d[IN])

print(ModName)
```

**Output:**

```
{'ClickUrl': 'HTTP', 'AngryUser': 'HATE', 'HelloGoodBye': 'HELLO', 'Social': ['TEAM_WELLNESS', 'TEAM_MEMBERS']}
```

**Alternative solution:**

```
data = {"UserIntents": [{"FirstVariation": "How is the Alchemy team doing?", "IntentName": "TEAM_WELLNESS", "ModuleName": "Social", }, {
    "FirstVariation": "I'd like to learn more about the team", "IntentName": "TEAM_MEMBERS", "ModuleName": "Social", }]}

ModName = {'ClickUrl': 'HTTP', 'AngryUser': 'HATE', 'HelloGoodBye': 'HELLO'}

MN = 'ModuleName'
IN = 'IntentName'
UI = 'UserIntents'

control = {}

for d in data[UI]:
    key = d[MN]
    if suffix := control.setdefault(key, 0):
        ModName[f'{key}_{suffix}'] = d[IN]
    else:
        ModName[key] = d[IN]
    control[key] += 1
    
print(ModName)
```

**Output:**

```
{'ClickUrl': 'HTTP', 'AngryUser': 'HATE', 'HelloGoodBye': 'HELLO', 'Social': 'TEAM_WELLNESS', 'Social_1': 'TEAM_MEMBERS'}
```

Comment: Thank you I went with the first option and it worked well

Comment: Also the reason I added about the suffix part is due to the fact that I wanted to extract another key (Description) from the JSON as:"UserIntents":[{"ModuleName":"Social","Description": "How is the Alchemy team doing?"},{"ModuleName": "Social","Description": "I'd like to learn more about the team"}] , it somehow worked with : Description_list.setdefault(d[MN], []).append(d[DL]) , but now when I am trying to set this in a string, it is overriding the first value from Description_list and adding only:I'd like to learn more about the team,not sure if you got it or maybe I need a different ques

Comment: Following question added : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72463331/add-text-in-the-trsx-element-node-via-a-dictionary-containing-list-of-strings