# Add text in the trsx Element Node via a dictionary containing list of Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, overriding, key-value

I have a JSON file from which I want to pick :Description and put in the dictionary  Description_List.
JSON data :

```
"UserIntents":[{
            
            
            "IntentName": "TEAM_WELLNESS",
            "ModuleName": "Social",
            "Description": "How is the Alchemy team doing?"
            },
            
            {
            
            
            "IntentName": "TEAM_MEMBERS",
            "ModuleName": "Social",
            "Description": "I'd like to learn more about the team"
            
            }]
```

Python code :

```
MN = 'ModuleName'
IN = 'IntentName'
UI = 'UserIntents'

for d in data[UI]:
    ModName_Social.setdefault(d[MN], []).append(d[IN])
    Description_list.setdefault(d[MN], []).append(d[DL])
```

Now, the Description_list contains the following output :

```
Description_list {'Social': ['How is the Alchemy team doing?', "I'd like to learn more about the team"]}
```

Now, I have created an element from the Element_tree as :

```
sample_node = SubElement(samples, NODE_CONSTANTS['sample_node'])
```

which is nothing but a sample node in the trsx file as :

```
<sample intentref="SOCIAL_TEAM_WELLNESS" count="1" excluded="true">I'd like to learn more about the team</sample>
    <sample intentref="SOCIAL_TEAM_MEMBERS" count="1" excluded="true">I'd like to learn more about the team</sample>
```

Now, when I ran the loop inside the Description_list dict, it is being printed that it is trying to set both of the strings to the sample_node element , so the expected output should be like:

```
<sample intentref="SOCIAL_TEAM_WELLNESS" count="1" excluded="true">How is the Alchemy team doing</sample>
    <sample intentref="SOCIAL_TEAM_MEMBERS" count="1" excluded="true">I'd like to learn more about the team</sample>
```

But the current output is :

```
<sample intentref="SOCIAL_TEAM_WELLNESS" count="1" excluded="true">I'd like to learn more about the team</sample>
    <sample intentref="SOCIAL_TEAM_MEMBERS" count="1" excluded="true">I'd like to learn more about the team</sample>
```

Which is like it is overriding the last value from the Description_list.

Python code :

```
for key in ModName_Social.keys():
     if key not in sample_node:
        val = ModName_Social[key]
        val1 = Description_list[key]
        for i in val:
            for j in val1:
                if key =='Social':
                    for i1 in val1:
                        i_x_0.text = i1 #gets only I'd like to learn more about the team
                        #i_x_0.text = ''.join(i1) #gets again I'd like to learn more about the team
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work considering you want to extract one by one from the list and assign to the node

```
for i1 in val1:
  length = len(val1)
  i1 =0   
  while i1 < length:                                                                               
    i_x_0.text = ''.join(val1[i1])
    i1 += 1
```

Comment: The logic is right, but somehow while setting the text, it is only setting the I'd like to learn more about the team in both of the samples.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking more into this and I believe the following will solve your overriding issues :

```
 if type(Description_list[key]) is  list:
                                                                                
 
    if a1 =='SOCIAL_TEAM_WELLNESS': 
                                                                                        
      i_x_0.text =Description_list[key][0]
                                                                                    
   else:
                                                                                        
      i_x_0.text = j
```

Comment: It solved the issue , result :   <sample intentref="SOCIAL_TEAM_WELLNESS" count="1" excluded="true">How is the Alchemy team doing?</sample>
    <sample intentref="SOCIAL_TEAM_MEMBERS" count="1" excluded="true">I'd like to learn more about the team</sample> , big thanks